# Hashicorp Vault не срабатывает доступ к секрету даже для root-политики

Tags: vault, hashicorp

Сначала я пробовал добиться, чтобы токен выпущенный для Approle получил доступ к секрету.
Но теперь даже вот так выпущенный токен получает в ответ 404.
`vault token create -policy=root`

При этом если воспользоваться root_token-ом изначальным, секрет доступен.

Путь к секрету:
`/v1/cubbyhole/src`

Созданная для эксперимента политика выглядит так:

```
path "cubbyhole/*" {
    capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}
```

Но после того, как она не срабатывала, перешел на эксперименты с root-политикой